# Should I use MVVM when the Data comes from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and have a project that uses Entity Framework.
Can I use MVVM or is it better not to?
Where shall I encapsulate the EF? in the viewModel or in the Model?
And how to handle the notification for Database changes ? cause the EntityFramework just query the first time and not periodically.

Thanks in advance, Kfir

Comment: `EF -> Service Layer -> View Model -> Controller -> View`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer

Comment: I think it should be like `EF -> DAL (Repository Operations) -> Service Layer (Business Logic) -> ViewModel (Interact with Services and will have properties which will bind with View) -> View (Render UI)`

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use MVVM when the Data comes from Entity Framework

Sure! MVVM is a pattern that helps producing testable code with a strong separation between view and model. So even if the data comes from EF, it's OK to use it.

> Where shall I encapsulate the EF?

It depends on the overall architecture of your project. A WPF application that directly calls the database won't have the same architecture than a 3-tier application composed of a WPF client that calls a service, and a service that calls the database.

I always recommend the 3-tier architecture (using IIS <- WCF -> WPF): the WPF application that implements MVVM won't directly call the database. In this case, the WPF application won't even know there is Entity Framework. The model will be the proxy to call your services, and Entity Framwork will be on the server side only.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer